# New features of WPF 4?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I've been unable to find articles describing in any detailed manner the new features of WPF in .Net 4.0. Where could I find that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jaime Rodriguez has a [good breakdown](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/05/27/wpf-4-and-net-framework-4-beta-1-list-of-features-totrack.aspx) of the features to expect for WPF in .NET 4, as well as their current status / availability in the beta version of .NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a video from MIX that highlights several features.

http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T39F

There are several other available from Channel 9

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=%22WPF%204%22&ac=3

Answer (score 2):

[What's New in WPF Version 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx)